# Will the Android device still run at the next startup if once happens a database locked

Tags: android-sqlite, locked

my friends:
  I am working on a Android App.In a cloud test, I found that some devices happened an error——"database is locked".Considering that i have not met the error,so i wonder that once the error happens on a device, will the device run nomally at the next startup.My worry is the database will be locked forever if  the application won't clear cache or uninstalls.
Thinks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E...It seems that few guys come with this issue.Luckily it reappeared on my device finally.Then i can answer it myself.The answer is TRUE,Once happened,it will appear at the next launch, which is very horrible for users.I am working hard to fix it.